# Могу ли я в android c помощью contentResolver.query создавать новые папки и отображать их?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Сейчас объясню более подробно что я имею ввиду. Ситуация такая: Есть приложение которое создает папки в определенной папке в оновном это DCIM на телефоне и карте памяти. При нажатии на папку запускается камера этого приложения, ты фотаешь и снимок сохраняется в нажатую папку. Все было хорошо, но видимо для создания, видимо для сохранения файлов в нужную папку и создания этих папок android 11 и выше потребовал доступ ко всем файлам, я его реализовал добавив нужный код и запись в manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` Когда обновлял приложение в гугл плей прилетел отказ:

```
App Status: Rejected

Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

    
Issue: Need to use Media Store API or No Access to Files

You have requested access to All Files Access permission but it appears that your app's core feature requires access to only Media Files or does not need access to any Files. In case your app needs access to Media Files, with the MediaStore API, apps can contribute and access media that's available on an external storage volume without the need for the access all files permission.

Please update your app so that the feature uses Media Store APIs and remove All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.
```

Я так понял гугл хочет чтобы я убрал `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` потому что приложение работает только с медиафайлами, они хотят чтобы я использовал запрос через контент провайдер (кажется так называется):

```
applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.media-type.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    selection,
    selectionArgs,
    sortOrder)
```

Вот гайд : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media
Но я так понял так нельзя выводить файлы из определенный папки, так же как и создавать папки или сохранять файлы в определенные папки? Если нельзя, то конечно буду писать апелляцию, потому что это убивает основной функционал приложения. Я извиняюсь, я конечно еще перечитаю, просто тема не простая и я запутался.

Comment: Да, такое возможно, более того для Андроида 11, 12 можно писать в определенные папки без разрешения WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: То есть мне надо будет все переписывать? Создание папок поддержуется?

Comment: Ну в определенных папках, так медиа можно писать в Picture и DCIM а там уже делайте подпапки на свое усмотрение, я делал имя своего приложения и далее по необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо. Попытаюсь разобраться.